# JavaFX: " Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" Error on JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-8

After selecting date on my DatePicker I see those errors:

```
E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.8\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\charsets.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\deploy.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\javaws.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jce.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jfr.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jsse.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\plugin.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\resources.jar;E:\все jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\ogobe\IdeaProjects\YSK_1\out\production\YSK_1;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.8\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain sample.Main
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(DatePickerSkin.java:147)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setValue(ComboBoxBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerContent.selectDayCell(DatePickerContent.java:689)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerContent.lambda$createDayCells$174(DatePickerContent.java:731)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Controller.getDate(Controller.java:72)
    ... 70 more
number of years: 1
number of months: 0
number of days: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Controller.java:

```
package sample;

import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.time.Period;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker date_1;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker date_2;

    @FXML
    private Button buttonAdd;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> choiceBox;

    @FXML
    private TextField lavozm;

    @FXML
    private Label year;

    @FXML
    private Label month;

    @FXML
    private Label yearOfIIN;

    @FXML
    private Label monthOfXis;

    @FXML
    private Label dayOfXis;


    public void getDate(ActionEvent event) {

        LocalDate dt1 = date_1.getValue();
        Calendar c =  Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(dt1.getYear(), dt1.getMonthValue(), dt1.getDayOfMonth());
        Date date1 = c.getTime();

        LocalDate dt2 = date_2.getValue();
        Calendar c2 =  Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.set(dt2.getYear(), dt2.getMonthValue(), dt2.getDayOfMonth());
        Date date2 = c.getTime();


        Period age = Period.between(dt1, dt2);


        int years = age.getYears();
        int months = age.getMonths();
        int days = age.getDays();



        System.out.println("number of years: " + years);
        System.out.println("number of months: " + months);
        System.out.println("number of days: " +  days);

    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("YSK");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 550));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="829.0" xmlns="javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="68.0" prefWidth="829.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1d90ed;">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="521.0" layoutY="21.0" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="269.0" promptText="Ходим исм шарфи" style="-fx-background-color: #EAFAFA;" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <DatePicker fx:id="date_1" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="123.0" onAction="#getDate" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="149.0" promptText="Боши" />
      <DatePicker fx:id="date_2" layoutX="176.0" layoutY="124.0" onAction="#getDate" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="149.0" promptText="Якуни" />
      <Button fx:id="buttonAdd" layoutX="387.0" layoutY="172.0" minWidth="26.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="56.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1d90ed;" text="+" />
      <ChoiceBox fx:id="choiceBox" layoutX="332.0" layoutY="124.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="48.0" />
      <Text layoutX="28.0" layoutY="438.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Календар хисобида:" />
      <Text layoutX="65.0" layoutY="467.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Имтиез блан:" />
      <TextField fx:id="lavozm" layoutX="395.0" layoutY="124.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="185.0" promptText="Лавозм" />
      <Text layoutX="624.0" layoutY="143.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="йил" />
      <Text layoutX="750.0" layoutY="144.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="кун" />
      <Text layoutX="689.0" layoutY="143.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="ой" />
      <Label fx:id="year" layoutX="587.0" layoutY="126.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="28.0" />
      <Label fx:id="month" layoutX="654.0" layoutY="127.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="28.0" />
      <Label fx:id="month" layoutX="715.0" layoutY="127.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="28.0" />
      <Text layoutX="187.0" layoutY="437.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="йил" />
      <Text layoutX="313.0" layoutY="438.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="кун" />
      <Text layoutX="252.0" layoutY="437.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="ой" />
      <Label fx:id="year" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="420.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="28.0" />
      <Label fx:id="month" layoutX="217.0" layoutY="421.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="28.0" />
      <Label fx:id="month" layoutX="278.0" layoutY="421.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="28.0" />
      <Text layoutX="191.0" layoutY="466.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="йил" />
      <Text layoutX="317.0" layoutY="467.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="кун" />
      <Text layoutX="256.0" layoutY="466.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="ой" />
      <Label fx:id="yearOfIIN" layoutX="154.0" layoutY="449.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="28.0" />
      <Label fx:id="monthOfXis" layoutX="221.0" layoutY="450.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="28.0" />
      <Label fx:id="dayOfXis" layoutX="282.0" layoutY="450.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="28.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at sample.Controller.getDate(Controller.java:72)`  Which line is line 72?

Comment: If I counted right, `date_2` is null.

Comment: Well, this is the task of this program to count how many days between two dates, and in another ChoiceBox it was possible to multiply the date that came out, yes, I know it sounds very strange, my first strange and incomprehensible task


As I understood, I Should change getDay on controller to return exit? @jewelsea

Comment: Replaced comments with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is going wrong**

dt2 is null, which makes sense because the getDate method in invoked as the onAction handler referenced in fxml for both date_1 and date_2 date pickers.

Whichever one you use to pick a date first, the other will have a null value for the picked date because you can only pick one date at a time.

**How to fix it**

If either date_1.getValue() or date_2.getValue() is null, the getDate method should be changed to exit (via return).

The method appears to be calculating the period between the two dates (which doesn't make sense for a null date).

Once the user has picked both dates, the call would go through and the period would be calculated correctly.

At the beginning of getDate(), write:

```
if (date_1.getValue() == null || date_2.getValue() == null) {
    System.out.println(“Both dates not yet chosen, will not calculate period”);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#getDate', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
/C:/Users/ogobe/IdeaProjects/YSK_1/out/production/YSK_1/sample/sample.fxml:18

Comment: That is an unrelated error.  You made some other change to your application. Perhaps you changed the method signature or fxml.  It is no longer even able to call your method. It is impossible to know without seeing all of the updated code. You can edit the question or create a new one to provide a [mcve].